# Erro ao conectar com o banco!

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Fiz uma pagina para cadastrar informações de um aluno no banco de dados mysql, mas ao enviar os dados do formulario, ele me retorna estes erros: 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\EasyTec\cadastra_usuario.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\EasyTec\cadastra_usuario.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EasyTec\cadastra_usuario.php on line 12

cadastro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conexao:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: poste seu código para que todos consigam ver melhor qual o problema e consigam lhe orientar

Comment: Blz, adicionei por foto já que o site comeu meu codigo

Comment: na conexão.php não precisar criar esse **$mysqli** fora da função, e tbm precisou você atribuir o return da sua função a alguma variavel da cadastro.php

Comment: Deixa eu ver bem, então o certo é colocar o $mysqli como parametro?É que sou leigo em php

Comment: tira o $mysqli que ta fora da função abrirConexão no arquivo conexão.php, no cadastro.php você coloca faz isso abaixo do include: **$mysqli = abrirConexão()** e testa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, no seu arquivo cadastro você precisa chamar o método abrirConexão() para depois enviar a sua query.
Assim:

```
<?php
  include "conexao.php";
  $mysqli = abrirConexao();

  //Aqui o restante da sua classe cadastro.

?>
```

E no seu arquivo conexao.php pode excluir aquele primeiro `$mysqli` que esta logo acima da função `abrirConexao()`.

Comment: Era isso ai mesmo man, mt obg!

Comment: @Lucas_Squ4nchy, que bom que deu certo! Se a reposta lhe foi ajudou considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Sim, vlw pelo aviso!